# Given $p_1^{a_1}+ \dots + p_r^{a_r} \leq n$, show that : $r \leq 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log(n)}}(1+o(1))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, prime-numbers, arithmetic

I post here because I really don't succeed to prove this :

> Given $p_1^{a_1}+ \dots + p_r^{a_r} \leq n$, $p_i$ distinct prime numbers and $a_i \in \mathbb{N} $, $a_i \geq 1$, $r \in \mathbb{N} $, show that : $r \leq
> 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log(n)}}(1+o(1))$

We know that, if we note $q_i$ the $i$-th prime numbers, we have :
$$n \geq  p_1^{a_1}+ \dots + p_r^{a_r} \geq q_1+ \dots + q_r \sim \frac{1}{2}r^2\log(r)$$

by the prime numbers theorem. So we have :

$$ n \geq \frac{1}{2}r^2\log(r)(1+o(1))$$

and then :

$$ r^2 \leq \frac{2n(1+o(1))}{\log(r)}$$

But I really don't succeed to finish from here.

Someone could help me, please ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is done, I have edited my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know that 
  $$ r^2 \le \frac{2n(1+o(1))}{\log(r)}, \tag{$\ast$} $$
you are almost there. Assume for a contradiction that $r>2\sqrt{n/\log n}(1+o(1))$. Then $\log(r)>\frac12\log n(1+o(1))$, and substituting this into ($\ast$) you get
  $$ r^2 < \frac{4n}{\log(n)}(1+o(1)). $$
It remains to take the square root.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: I've shown the result is incorrect. $\sum_{m\le x}\frac{m}{\log m} \sim \sum_{m\le x}\frac{m^2}{2\log m}-\frac{(m-1)^2}{2\log (m-1)}$ @FleurDeLys

Comment: @reuns Could you elaborate: exactly what and why is incorrect? (And, maybe, this should be a comment to the original problem, not to my answer - unless there is a problem with the answer?)

Comment: See my answer, it is $n\log n$ not $n/\log n$

Answer (score 1):

The PNT implies $$\sum_{p \le x} p =(1+o(1)) \sum_{2 \le m \le x} \frac{m}{\log m}=(1+o(1)) \frac{x^2}{2 \log x}$$ Thus $$\sum_{p \le x} p\le n \implies x^2 \le (1+o(1)) n \log n \implies  x \le (1+o(1)) n^{1/2} \log^{1/2} n$$

Comment: To obtain $\frac{n^{1/2}}{ \log^{1/2} n}$ you need to look at $\sum_{p \le x} p \ln^2 p$

Comment: How do you do for estimating the sum of $\frac{m}{log(m)}$ ? I have tried to compare with the integral but I didn't succeed to finish.

Comment: In the sum over $m$, the range of summation should be $m<(1+o(1))x/\log x$, right?